# Disk acting full when it isn't

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have just reinstalled Windows 10 on my laptop.

I tried to install Chrome, but got error 112 (which seems to mean disk full).

I tried to install Steam, and it installed fine, but when it tries to update it downloads, then says it needs to be online, the end of the log looks like this:

```
[2018-05-25 16:46:04] Downloading update (70,591 of 166,320 KB)...
[2018-05-25 16:46:17] Error: Saving package (tenfoot_images_all) failed.
[2018-05-25 16:46:17] Error: Steam needs to be online to update.     Please confirm your network connection and try again.
[2018-05-25 16:46:21] Shutdown
```

I checked, and I'm only using 20GB out of 900 on the C drive (the only drive at the moment).

I can download files, the issue seems to only affect installers, I have tried turning off Windows Firewall, but it made no difference.

Is there anything I can do to try to fix this?

## Screenshots

### Steam

[image]

### Chrome

[image]

## Edit

I tried to use the Windows USB Creator to re-install, but I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of the actual error message?

Comment: I've added them, I am not sure how much help they are though

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1) If you just reinstalled Windows 10 onto your laptop I would make sure all your network drivers are installed. Go into device manager and make sure you see no yellow exclamation triangles.  Go to the laptop manufacturer's website, get to the drivers section, and you can go through there to double check.

2) With new installations or re-installations, Windows 10 tries to download the latest updates.  When this happens it can screw with your bandwidth when trying to download other things.  Temporarily disable and updates Windows is doing.  You should then have a smoother network connection.